# Unable to read JSON object value in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to read the value of a Json object with a given key. However, my key is a bit complicated thus i get undefined on the console. I am sure i am not using it the right way ? can someone point my mistake ?

Json  key: value

```
relevant=(pooled + assigned + unknown + dropping) : 230
```

Node.js

```
    data = JSON.parse(buffer);

    var dump = "  relevant=(pooled + assigned + unknown + dropping)  ";
    console.log(data.totals.dump);
```

Comment: There is no JSON here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should not call like `data.totals.dump` it will search for a key `dump` in data.totals.

use `data.totals[dump]` instead. Then it'll search for key what is value of dump.

and for key purpose better do once `Object.keys(data.totals)` to see what are the keys in my object.